# Convert SQL WHERE query to JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need help converting this WHERE query into JOIN. I will be following the same pattern for other queries. Thank you.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT r.recipe_id, r.recipe_name, r.recipe_image,
                r.recipe_duration, r.recipe_serving, r.recipe_difficulty, 
                (SELECT category_name 
                FROM tbl_category 
                WHERE r.category_id = category_id) AS category_name, 
                (SELECT cuisine_name 
                FROM tbl_cuisine 
                WHERE r.cuisine_id = cuisine_id) AS cuisine_name, 
                r.recipe_ingredients, r.recipe_steps, r.date, r.user_id, 
                u.fname, u.lname, u.image, r.language 
        FROM tbl_recipe r, tbl_user u 
        WHERE r.category_id like '%{$category_name}%' 
        AND u.id = r.user_id 
        AND r.language = '$language' 
        GROUP BY r.recipe_id 
        ORDER BY r.recipe_id ASC";
```

Comment: If you can read it, there is just a chance you can debug it

Comment: I need help writing it in a better way, for now, it works

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Thank you for this information, I am still new to PHP, just a question which is better mysqli or pdo?

Comment: Which ever one you like to use the most. People do have preferences, but I wont force mine on you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part, you just change your comma separated tables to JOIN clauses.  The "ON" clause of the join is what comes from the WHERE clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      r.recipe_id, 
      r.recipe_name, 
      r.recipe_image,
      r.recipe_duration, 
      r.recipe_serving, 
      r.recipe_difficulty, 
      (SELECT category_name 
          FROM tbl_category 
          WHERE r.category_id = category_id) AS category_name, 
      (SELECT cuisine_name 
          FROM tbl_cuisine 
          WHERE r.cuisine_id = cuisine_id) AS cuisine_name, 
      r.recipe_ingredients, 
      r.recipe_steps, 
      r.date, 
      r.user_id, 
      u.fname, 
      u.lname, 
      u.image, 
      r.language 
   FROM 
      tbl_recipe r
         JOIN tbl_user u 
            on r.user_id = u.id
   WHERE 
          r.category_id like '%{$category_name}%' 
      AND r.language = '$language' 
   GROUP BY 
      r.recipe_id 
   ORDER BY 
      r.recipe_id ASC
```

Also, instead of column-based select, you could pullthe category and cuisine joined as well.  More efficient than query for every record

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      r.recipe_id, 
      r.recipe_name, 
      r.recipe_image,
      r.recipe_duration, 
      r.recipe_serving, 
      r.recipe_difficulty,
      cat.category_name, 
      cn.cuisine_name, 
      r.recipe_ingredients, 
      r.recipe_steps, 
      r.date, 
      r.user_id, 
      u.fname, 
      u.lname, 
      u.image, 
      r.language 
   FROM 
      tbl_recipe r
         JOIN tbl_user u 
            on r.user_id = u.id
         JOIN tbl_category cat
            on r.category_id = cat.category_id 
         JOIN cuisine_name cn
            on r.cuisine_id = cn.cuisine_id 
   WHERE 
          r.category_id like '%{$category_name}%' 
      AND r.language = '$language' 
   GROUP BY 
      r.recipe_id 
   ORDER BY 
      r.recipe_id ASC
```

Also notice, from left-to-right my "join/on" conditions are listing the left table/alias = what I am joining TO table/alias.  Helps keep directional awareness of from here to there the tables are joined.

In addition as other person noted in comment, you are open to SQL-Injection and should always parameterize your queries and clean your input source values... So research into SQL-Injection and data cleansing too.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

write the join using the `AND u.id = r.user_id` and then remove the `AND u.id = r.user_id`

```
FROM tbl_recipe r
    LEFT JOIN tbl_user u ON u.id = r.user_id 
WHERE r.category_id like '%{$category_name}%' 
AND r.language = '$language'
```

> Thsi still has issues with [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
> Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
> You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values